# Create record with Relation Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi i have the next code for create my records

```
    Institution::create($request->all());



    User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
        'phone' => $request['phone'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
        'state' => 1,
        'profile_id' => 1,
        'institution_id' => Institution::max('id'),
        ]);
```

The last attributes for the User thats correct implement so?
The last 3 user attributes , it is correct to do it that way? or is there a better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Institution::max('id')` creates a race condition. Since the `create()` static method of `Eloquent::Model` returns the newly-created model, you can just do:

```
    $institution = Institution::create($request->all());

    User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
        'phone' => $request['phone'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
        'state_id' => 1,
        'profile_id' => 1,
        'institution_id' => $institution->id,
        ]);
```

Creating a record with known parent ids is generally fine if your goal is to minimize the number of database queries and you have the ids of the related models.

Another way to do it, though it triggers more update queries, is to use Eloquent's [built-in methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) for adding related models. For example:

```
    $institution = Institution::create($request->all());

    $state = State::find(1);
    $profile = Profile::find(1);

    $user = new User([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
        'phone' => $request['phone'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password']
        ]);

    $user->state()->associate($state);
    $user->profile()->associate($profile);
    $user->profile()->associate($institution);

    $user->save();
```

However, in this situation, since the related models are not already loaded, and you know their ids, there is no need to fetch them only to associate them with the User.

Comment: Thank you for your answer will put into practice :D

Comment: Edited the link to point to the Laravel 5.1 docs (rather than 4.2).