# how i will create data insert into Different tow tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

how i will create data insert into Different tow tables ?
Dear All Developer
how i will create data insert into Different  tow  tables (thumbnails - recipes ) in function store RecipesController, and i have Relationships with tables  thumbnail_id foreign keys.
tables thumbnails :

```
Schema::create('thumbnails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        //$table->comment('Business calculations');
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->comment('foreign key tables users');

       // $table->unsignedBigInteger('recipes_ID')->unsigned();
      //  $table->foreign('recipes_ID')->references('id')->on('recipes')->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('slug')->nullable()->unique()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('thumbnail')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('path')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('size')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        //$table->string('images')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
       // $table->string('alt')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        //$table->comment('Business calculations');
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_ID')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_ID')->references('id')->on('users')->comment('foreign key tables users');



        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuisines_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cuisines_id')->references('id')->on('cuisines')->comment('foreign key tables cuisines');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('thumbnail_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('thumbnail_id')->references('id')->on('thumbnails')->comment('foreign key tables photos');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->comment('foreign key tables categories');

        $table->string('title')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('slug')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->text('dsescription')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('youtubevideo')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('method')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('difficlty')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('preptime')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('cooktime')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('total')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('servings')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->string('yield')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->text('ingredients')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->text('directions')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->text('nutritionFacts')->nullable()->comment('foreign key tables users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

public function store(StorerecipesRequest $request)
   {


       $thumbnails =new thumbnails;

       if ($request->hasFile('thumbnails')) {
           $name = $request->file('thumbnails')->getClientOriginalName();
           $size = $request->file('thumbnails')->getSize();
           $path = $request->file('thumbnails')->storeAs('public/Recipes/thumbnails', $name);
       }

       $thumbnails = thumbnails::create([

            [ 'thumbnails' => $request->$name],
            [ 'path' => $request->$path ],
            [ 'size' => $request->$size ]
       ]);

       $recipes = new Recipes;

       $recipes = recipes::create([
           [ 'cuisines_id' => $request->cuisines_id ],
           [ 'category_id' => $request->category_id ],
           [ 'thumbnail_id' => $request->thumbnail_id ],
           [ 'name' => $request->name ],
           [ 'slug' => $request->slug ],
           [ 'dsescription' => $request->dsescription ],
           [ 'file' => $request->file ],
           [ 'youtubevideo' => $request->youtubevideo ],
           [ 'method' => $request->method ],
           [ 'difficlty' => $request->difficlty ],
           [ 'preptime' => $request->preptime ],
           [ 'cooktime' => $request->cooktime ],
           [ 'total' => $request->total ],
           [ 'servings' => $request->servings ],
           [ 'yield' => $request->yield ],
           [ 'ingredients' => $request->ingredients ],
           [ 'directions' => $request->directions ],
           [ 'nutritionFacts' => $request->nutritionFacts ],
       ]);

       $recipes->save();



       return redirect()->route('Recipes.show')->with('success', 'Recipes destroy successfully.');
   }


ErrorException
Undefined variable: name
[ 'thumbnails' => $request->$name],
```

I apologize for my poor writing and appreciate your help
thank you

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create record with Relation Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305676/create-record-with-relation-laravel-5-1)